# How to join the tables in Tableau as they are joined in ER diagram

Tags: tableau-api

I want to join tables in tableau but, when I am adding any table to join it is getting joined with the 1st table I added irrespective of keys. Even if tables do not have same keys table is getting joined.

```
Example: Sales to be joined with OnlineSales and Customer to be joined with OnlineSales but Customer is getting joined with Sales.
```

I tried using custom SQL as well but it is not working.

Comment: Tableau guesses the joins when you first set them up. But not all its guesses are right. But you can set the join to be whatever you want manually to override the guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the Venn diagram icon for the join and set the left and right keys as desired. You can choose different tables for each join key; you aren't limited to the ones listed first. After you save your join key choices, the diagram will update to show which tables are involved.

No need for custom SQL. In fact, save custom SQL for the rare situation where Tableau gives you no other choice because Custom SQL prevents useful query optimizations.